# Read only scope for Google admin settings API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth, google-admin-settings-api

I was trying to retrieve the organization name of the user using the OAuth mechanism (in java on Google app engine). The scope that I used is

> https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/

However this scope is giving `Manage your domain settings` option, which seems very scary for the end customers. Attached below is the screenshot of that.

[image: with out read only option]

so, is there is a **read only version** of this scope, so that it can be only `View your domain settings`

I tried using the following scopes in the OAuth playground,

> https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain.readonly
>
> https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/#readonly

but every time I was bit by invalid oauth scopes URI. Attached below is the screenshot.

[image: With readonly option]

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is documented at [1]. You can use "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly" scope. Org Unit will be listed under "orgUnitPath" of the returned user resource.

[1] - https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem what you can do is:
go to Admin Console > Security > API Controls > Domain Wide Delegation

Select you App, click on Edit and add your scope **"https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain"**

Now click on Authorise. Done
Now you can generate access token by including this scope and access Google Admin Setting API.

Comment: That's not read only scope